# How to convert string field to object Id inside embedded document of already existing record?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection tblTesting with records saved like

```
    {
     "_id": ObjectId("5de9f044af647f21780056e1"),
     "name": "abc",
     "creditAccountDetails": {
         "creditAccountNumber": "0200040671890190",
         "creditAccountNumberId": "5db2efb5590a065abc006b12"
      } 
    }
```

The embedded document "creditAccountDetails" has been wrongly saved. Now I am trying to update them by using mongodb command like

```
  db.tblTesting.updateMany
   {},
   [
        { $set: { creditAccountDetails: [[ 'creditAccountNumberId' : ObjectId ($creditAccountNumber) ]] } },
    {}
   ]
  )
```

Basically I want that the command should be able to update all the records like

```
    {
     "_id": ObjectId("5de9f044af647f21780056e1"),
     "name": "abc",
     "creditAccountDetails":[ {
         "creditAccountNumber": "0200040671890190",
         "creditAccountNumberId": ObjectId("5db2efb5590a065abc006b12")
      } 
     ]
    }
```

Please help!!!

Note that I am using mongo db 4.0

Comment: Apart from converting string to valid `ObjectId`, you want to convert `creditAccountDetails` from object to an array as well??

Comment: yes exactly... u r right

Answer (score 2):

Since you are on **mongodb version 4.0**, which does not allow referring document fields in an update. A way to do this is iterate via [**`cursor`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/) on the collection and update the field.

```
var cursor = db.collection.find({});

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var doc = cursor.next();
  db.collection.updateOne(
    {
      _id: doc._id
    },
    {
      $set: {
        creditAccountDetails: [
          {
            creditAccountNumber: doc.creditAccountDetails.creditAccountNumber,
            creditAccountNumberId: ObjectId(
              doc.creditAccountDetails.creditAccountNumberId
            )
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  );
}
```

For readers who are on **Mongodb 4.2.0+** which allows using aggregation pipeline ops in update methods [**`updateOne`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#update-with-aggregation-pipeline), [**`updateMany`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline) where document fields can be used as part of [**`$set`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/).

```
db.collection.updateMany({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      creditAccountDetails: [
        {
          creditAccountNumber: "$creditAccountDetails.creditAccountNumber",
          creditAccountNumberId: {
            $toObjectId: "$creditAccountDetails.creditAccountNumberId"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

`tblTesting`'s schema should have define type `ObjectId` for `creditAccountNumberId`
below example I used `mongoose`

```
const tblTesting = mongoose.Schema({
    ....
    creditAccountNumberId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    },
    ....

}, {
    collection: 'tblTesting',
    timestamps: true,
    strict: false,
})
```

Comment: This answer, along with most or all of the other 11 you've posted in the last day, appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.

Comment: This does not answer the question, `mongoose` is not mentioned at all in the question. Schema and validation is not mentioned in the question either.